# JPA - Getting data through a foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm new to JPA, I used JDBC and now trying to switch it over to JPA usage. I've got these two classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "work_entry")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w"),
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findByWorkEntryId", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.workEntryId = :workEntryId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findByDate", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.date = :date"),
@NamedQuery(name = "WorkEntry.findByHoursWorked", query = "SELECT w FROM WorkEntry w WHERE w.hoursWorked = :hoursWorked")})
public class WorkEntry implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "work_entry_id")
private Integer workEntryId;
@Column(name = "date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "hours_worked")
private Double hoursWorked;
@JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", referencedColumnName = "activity_id")
@ManyToOne
private Activity activityId;
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
@ManyToOne
private Customer customerId;

public WorkEntry() {
}

public WorkEntry(Date date, Double hoursWorked, Customer customerId, Activity activityId) {
    this.date = date;
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
    this.activityId = activityId;
    this.customerId = customerId;
}


public WorkEntry(Integer workEntryId) {
    this.workEntryId = workEntryId;
}

public Integer getWorkEntryId() {
    return workEntryId;
}

public void setWorkEntryId(Integer workEntryId) {
    this.workEntryId = workEntryId;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Double getHoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
}

public void setHoursWorked(Double hoursWorked) {
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public Activity getActivityId() {
    return activityId;
}

public void setActivityId(Activity activityId) {
    this.activityId = activityId;
}

public Customer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Customer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (workEntryId != null ? workEntryId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof WorkEntry)) {
        return false;
    }
    WorkEntry other = (WorkEntry) object;
    if ((this.workEntryId == null && other.workEntryId != null) || (this.workEntryId != null && !this.workEntryId.equals(other.workEntryId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "consultant.billing.entity.WorkEntry[ workEntryId=" + workEntryId + " ]";
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCustomerId", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.customerId = :customerId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.firstName = :firstName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByLastName", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.lastName = :lastName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByStreetAddress", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.streetAddress = :streetAddress"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByCity", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.city = :city"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByState", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.state = :state"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPostalCode", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.postalCode = :postalCode"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByPhoneNumber", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByEmail", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.email = :email")})
public class Customer implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "customer_id")
private Integer customerId;
@Size(max = 75)
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Size(max = 75)
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Size(max = 250)
@Column(name = "street_address")
private String streetAddress;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "city")
private String city;
@Size(max = 50)
@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "postal_code")
private String postalCode;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "phone_number")
private String phoneNumber;
// @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
@Size(max = 250)
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId")
private Collection<ExpenseEntry> expenseEntryCollection;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerId")
private Collection<WorkEntry> workEntryCollection;

public Customer() {
}

public Customer(Integer customerId, String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String postalCode, String phoneNumber, String email) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.email = email;
}

public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String streetAddress, String city, String state, String postalCode, String phoneNumber, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    this.city = city;
    this.state = state;
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.email = email;
}


public Customer(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public Integer getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public void setCustomerId(Integer customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getStreetAddress() {
    return streetAddress;
}

public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
    this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public String getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<ExpenseEntry> getExpenseEntryCollection() {
    return expenseEntryCollection;
}

public void setExpenseEntryCollection(Collection<ExpenseEntry> expenseEntryCollection) {
    this.expenseEntryCollection = expenseEntryCollection;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<WorkEntry> getWorkEntryCollection() {
    return workEntryCollection;
}

public void setWorkEntryCollection(Collection<WorkEntry> workEntryCollection) {
    this.workEntryCollection = workEntryCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (customerId != null ? customerId.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Customer)) {
        return false;
    }
    Customer other = (Customer) object;
    if ((this.customerId == null && other.customerId != null) || (this.customerId != null && !this.customerId.equals(other.customerId))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "consultant.billing.entity.Customer[ customerId=" + customerId + " ]";
}
```

Now, what I've done before is used a joined to get the WorkEntry based off the customerId. I know JPA is more object oriented and I want to know what would be the best way to go about getting all WorkEntries for a customerId and adding WorkEntries based off a customerId.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make more sense if you changed your definition to the folowing

```
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customer_id")
@ManyToOne
private Customer customer;
```

And change the corresponding getter and setter methods as well.

Then if you get a `WorkEntry` you can just get work entry.getCustomer ()

You and so need to be a bit more specific about the type in your Collection on Customer like List to give the provider some hints about how to implement the collection.

Once you have done that you should just be able to read the customer from the database and call customer.getWorkEntryCollection()

Comment: Makes senses. Thank you redge for the help!